# Bulk Insert and update performances C# "ADO.NET" Vs "Linq2SQL" Vs "EF-DataFirst approach"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, ado.net, azure-webjobs

I am writing a Azure Web job c# code for doing Bulk Insertion and Update in an existing Azure SQL Database.
Considering the performance which .NET data access technology should I select-ADO.NET/Linq2SQL/EF-DataFirst approach ?

Comment: It really depends on your task (we need more details), but i belive with Azure critical place will be on Network connection not on db.

Comment: We have background web job/Activity which will dump the data into SQL tables and Power BI will get the data or do transactions from the SQL DB.

Answer (score 3):

Raw ADO.NET with SqlBulkCopy will alway give you the best performance, as the other technologies are abstraction layers on top of ADO.NET